# PHP basics if page is 2+ will display the same page

Tags: php, selector

Hello guys I am using this script for my pagination:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '') {
   $pageno = $_GET['page']; /* Sanitize Here */
} else {
   /* You can redirect user to home page */
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($pageno)) {
  if($pageno == '1') {
     ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="examples">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <img id="one" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="two" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="three" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="four" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
        <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <img id="one" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="two" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="three" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="four" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <img id="one" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="two" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="three" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="four" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="pages">

       <div class="prev-blocked"></div>
              <a href="portfolio.php?page=2"><div class="next"></div></a>
<br /><br /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
<?php    
  } 
  elseif($pageno == '2') {
 ?>
 <div class="container">
 <br />
 <div class="alert alert-error">
  <b>Opps!</b> We could not find out the page you're requesting. <a href="index.php">Go back</a>
</div>
 </div>
<!--
<div class="container">
  <div class="examples">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <img id="one" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="two" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="three" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="four" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
        <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <img id="one" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="two" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="three" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="four" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <img id="one" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="two" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="three" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
          <div class="span3">
      <img id="four" src="img/example.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="pages">

       <a href="portfolio.php?page=1"><div class="prev"></div></a>
              <div class="next-blocked"></div>
<br /><br /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  -->
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Can you see the line

```
elseif($pageno == '2') {
```

It means that page .php?page=2 will display the content below

I want to make it so every page that is higher than the number 2 will display the same page.

I've tried these options:

```
elseif($pageno == '>=2') {

elseif($pageno == '>2') {
```

And nothing of them works, not even an error.
I doubt you can do something this way with that script but, is there any other way to do so that works?

Thanks.

Comment: You got a lot of correct answers. Don't forget to mark your favourite one as 'accepted'

Comment: I know will do thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I'm not sure that the other answers should be upvoted unless they provide new information not provided by the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ((int)$pageno >= 2)
```

... should do the trick.

It actually may be written without casting to integer (or using [**intval**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function), because PHP is weakly-typed language. But I'd prefer that form to show my intention in the code more clearly. In fact, I'd change this line...

```
$pageno = $_GET['page'];
```

... to this:

```
$pageno = (int)$_GET['page'];
```

... and proceed with direct number comparisons (like `$pageno === 1`)

Comment: Thanks worked! any idea where can I learn all of these selectors at? I mean I read the guide at w3school but never seen something like intaval.

Thanks again

Comment: I'd recommend to use `(int)` instead of `intval()` as [it's faster](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/php-casting-vs-intval/).

Answer (score 0):

elseif($pageno >= 2)

;)

Simple as it is maybe you look on php.net for more infos on if.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
elseif(intval($pageno, 10) >== 2)
```

The reason you don't get error is that `$pageno` is a string, so is `'2'`. So when you try to compare them using the equal operator, it is valid PHP. So, `'2'` is being compared to `'>2'`, or `'>=2', both of which are false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
elseif(intval($pageno) >= 2) {
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `intval()` function to cast your `$_GET['page']` as follows:

```
$pageno = intval($_GET['page']);
```

Then you can compare `$pageno` as an integer.

```
if($pageno >= 2 )
{

...

}
```